# Stopwatch- stop and start Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on a simple stopwatch. The problem is that the stopwatch automatically runs the moment you run the program and even if you press the stop button unable to make it stop.

```
class ClockApp(App):
    sw_started = False
    sw_seconds = 0

    def update_clock(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.sw_seconds += nap

    def update_time(self, nap):
        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')
        self.sw_seconds += nap
        minutes, seconds = divmod(self.sw_seconds, 60)
        self.root.ids.stopwatch.text = ('%02d:%02d.[size=40]%02d[/size]' % (int(minutes), int(seconds),
                                                                            int(seconds * 100 % 100)))

    def start_stop(self):
        self.root.ids.start_stop.text = ('Start'
                                         if self.sw_started else 'Stop')
        self.sw_started = not self.sw_started

    def reset(self):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.root.ids.start_stop.text = 'Start'
        self.sw_started = False
        self.sw_seconds = 0

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 0)


class ClockLayout(BoxLayout):
    time_prop = ObjectProperty(None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelBase.register(name='Roboto', fn_regular='Roboto-Thin.ttf', fn_bold='Roboto-Medium.ttf')

Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#101216')

ClockApp().run()
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? If not please include more, it seems to me that this doesn't account for the "automatically runs the moment you run the program" you have described

Comment: @HymnsForDisco updated the code sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time counting is duplicated in two different methods:

```py
    def update_clock(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.sw_seconds += nap # here

    def update_time(self, nap):
        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')
        self.sw_seconds += nap # and here
        # [...]
```

`update_clock` only counts up if `sw_started` is `True`, but `update_time` has no such check. The method you've scheduled with `schedule_interval` is `update_time`,  so the value of `sw_started` has no effect.

Either schedule `update_clock` instead:

```py
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 0)
```

...or add a conditional to `update_time`:

```py
    def update_time(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.root.ids.time.text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')
            self.sw_seconds += nap
            minutes, seconds = divmod(self.sw_seconds, 60)
            # [...]
```

Comment: thank you so much. I have updated the ```update_time``` to what you have suggested. However, this time when I press the reset button it does not work anymore.

Comment: yes sir it was working before. Only the stop button was not working. This time the stop and start are perfectly fine after I followed what you have suggested on the ```update_time```.